# Simple Atom application that downloads everything

Tags: download, rss, podcasts, atom-feed, feed-reader

I'm looking for a simple desktop application that downloads everything linked in an Atom feed. This isn't for reading blogs or listening to podcasts - simply using the feed as a notification service for new data. [Maybe a podcast manager could do this? The files wouldn't be audio though...]

Requirements:

- OSX and Windows (could be different applications for each platform)
- Runs in the background, doing its thing as quietly as possible (maybe notify user when an entry has downloaded)
- Must download every entry without prompting
- Can download huge data (5 Gb+ files)
- Must support username/password authentication (and not ask each time)
- Retains directory names (so "http://example.com/feed/my/directory/name" would store locally to "c:\my feeds\my\directory\name\file.dat")
- Free

Could also consider RSS applications, although Atom is preferred.

Comment: Have you tried any applications? Did they not fulfill your needs?

Comment: I've looked for some, but I actually don't see a lot of Atom readers out there - unless "RSS" is a catch-all term for both RSS and Atom. I think the requirement to maintain directory names could be tricky.

Comment: Most "RSS readers" are "feed readers", really. So they typically support Atom and the various RSS formats.